# pyqtgraph - Is it possible to have a ImageView without histogram?

Tags: python, pyqt, dicom, pyqtgraph

I currently have a [ImageView](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/imageview.html) showing a Dicom image, but i don't want that histogram on the side. And with possible,move those two buttons to another place. 
How can I make that?

Answer (score 12):

I know it's late, but for anybody trying to figure this out in the future who wants an imageview and NOT an imageitem:

Assuming you have an imageview labled imv and a boolean, show_histogram, you can toggle displaying the histogram (and the two buttons below it) with the following code.

```
if show_histogram:
    imv.ui.histogram.show()
    imv.ui.roiBtn.show()
    imv.ui.menuBtn.show()
else:
    imv.ui.histogram.hide()
    imv.ui.roiBtn.hide()
    imv.ui.menuBtn.hide()
```

Comment: For me, it's just in time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

The special thing with ImageView is that you get the histogram. Another way of display an image is by adding an [ImageItem](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/imageitem.html) to a basic plot and hiding the axes. Tackling the problem this way would give you good control over what your application shows.

Here is a code sample:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
plot = win.addPlot()

imagedata = np.random.random((256,256))
ii = pg.ImageItem(imagedata)
plot.addItem(ii)
plot.hideAxis('left')
plot.hideAxis('bottom')

import sys
if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

The start of an hacky approach would be by calling `ui.histogram.hide()` on your ImageView. Something like this

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
imv = pg.ImageView()
win.setCentralWidget(imv)
win.show()

imagedata = np.random.random((256,256))
imv.setImage(imagedata)
imv.ui.histogram.hide()

import sys
if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an ImageItem without an histogram on the side. Maybe it's what you're looking for.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

imageWidget = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
vb = imageWidget.addViewBox(row=1, col=1)
img = pg.ImageItem()
vb.addItem(img)
vb.setAspectLocked(True)
```

Comment: a simple copy-paste of this answer gives the error: 'QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget'

Comment: sorry for that, I added the QApplication constructor now, give it a try

Comment: thx, sorry if my questions are obvious: when I do that in the spyder's ipython console, it gets frozen and nothing happens. what's wrong ?

Comment: precisions: 1.I replaced 'PyQt4' by 'PyQt5' and 2. when I say 'frozen', I have a prompt with access to the history of commands, but I can't make any command anymore in this console, the interpreter just loops infinitely to next lines as if I had a parenthesis opened.

Comment: Hi. Try that in a normal python interpreter instead of in a ipython notebook. As far as I know, ipython is not meant to support PyQt applications

Comment: It's possible, but you need to run the `%gui qt` magic first